# How to make a JPanel reset?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, reset

I have a simple game of pong where when the user clicks a `JButton` which is displayed on the `JPanel` it should reset the game. How can I do this? I was thinking just remove the `JPanel` and add a new one (the `JPanel` contains all of the necessary code/class references for the game) I tried writing this however, and it didn't work, nothing happens. Here is my code:

**JFrame Class:**

```
public class Window extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    static int length = 1000;
    static int height = 1000;
    Display display = new Display();

    Window() {

        setTitle("Program Display");
        setSize(length + 22, height + 40);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton restart = new JButton("Start New Game");
        add(display);
        display.add(restart);
        restart.addActionListener(this);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        remove(display);
        Display display2 = new Display();
        JButton restart = new JButton("Start New Game");
        add(display2);
        display2.add(restart);
        restart.addActionListener(this);
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }
}
```

**JPanel Class:**

```
public class Display extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    int up = 0;
    int down = 500;
    double ballx = 500;
    double bally = 500;
    char ballDirection;
    Rectangle border;
    static Rectangle borderEast;
    static Rectangle borderNorth;
    static Rectangle borderSouth;
    static Rectangle borderWest;
    static boolean gameOver;
    Timer timer;
    Paddle p;
    Ball b;

    Display() {
        p = new Paddle();
        b = new Ball();
        up = p.up;
        down = p.down;
        ballx =  b.ballx;
        bally =  b.bally;
        ballDirection = b.ballDirection;
        initTimer();
        b.startBall();
        addKeyListener(p);
        setFocusable(true);


    }


    public void initTimer() {
        timer = new Timer(10, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void setUpBorders(Graphics2D g2d) {
        border = new Rectangle(0, 0, Window.length, Window.height);
        borderEast = new Rectangle(Window.length, 0, 2, Window.height);
        borderWest = new Rectangle(0, 0, 2, Window.height);
        borderSouth = new Rectangle(0, Window.height, Window.length, 2);
        borderNorth = new Rectangle(0, 0, Window.length, 2);
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.draw(border);

    }

    public void paintPaddle(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.setColor(new Color(0, 130, 130));
        g2d.fill(p.paddle);

    }

    public void paintBall(Graphics2D g2d) {

        g2d.setColor(new Color(0, 130, 130));
        g2d.fillOval((int) ballx, (int) bally, 20, 20);

    }



    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        setUpBorders(g2d);
        paintPaddle(g2d);
        paintBall(g2d);

        if(gameOver == true) {
                Font custom = new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 60);
                g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                g2d.setFont(custom);
                g2d.drawString("Game Over. Your score was: " + Ball.score + "!", 50, 500);

        }

    }




    public void checkBorderHit() {
        b.checkBorderHit();
        p.checkBorderHit();

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        up = p.up;
        down = p.down;
        ballx =  b.ballx;
        bally =  b.bally;
        ballDirection = b.ballDirection;

        b.moveBall();
        checkBorderHit();
        repaint();


    }
}
```

Comment: You create one or more model classes to hold the values of your game.  You display these values on the view.  To, restart, you reset the values in your model classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say what exactly doesn't work, but you forgot to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` after adding `display2`. If your problem was that after pressing the button nothing happens, this will probably solve it.

### Edit:

We still can't run you code, because the Ball and Paddle class are missing (my mistake for not mentioning that), but try to set important variables like `gameOver` false when first "mentioning them" (I don't know the proper term, just do `static boolean gameOver = false;` instead of `static boolean gameOver;`). Do this in all other classes also. Sorry for not saying which variables you exactly must change, but I'm not saying anything I'm not 100% sure about without being able to test it :P (maybe a more experienced person can help you more)

Comment: @AshwinGupta So does it work after adding `revalidate()` and `repaint()`?

Comment: Sort of. It resets the ball but I can no longer control the paddle and the game over message that I have continues to appear in the screen

Comment: It's also very glitchy and displaying the ball multiple times, I'm guessing that this wasn't exactly the right way to achieve what I want

Comment: @AshwinGupta Atleast I can't help you more without you posting a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)/[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) - I suspect that you don't properly reset all the variables in your class, but I can't tell. (You can also just post your whole Display class, I gues...)

Comment: Ya you are probably right. I'll look through it all its probably just an error with my code. I also probably need to understand how  multiple Jpanels work. At least what you said sort of made it work. Thanks.

Comment: @AshwinGupta *"At least what you said sort of made it work"* - But you want it to work completely, right? Please consider reading my links or posting your class for better help. Accepting an answer that solves half of your problem isn't really right. (IMO)

Comment: Thats fine, I think I might know the problem. When I set game over to true it dosent actually reset the variables correctly in ball/paddle. So basically the reason its not working is the ball is still where it previously was.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87827/discussion-between-ashwin-gupta-and-luxxminer).